# Selecting values from one column and passing corresponding values from another column in MySQL queries in Shiny

Tags: mysql, shiny, sqldf

I have a **Shiny** app querying large data from a **MySQL database** but for purposes of this question I will use **SQLDF** which is similar in syntax on Shiny environment.

A mock up of my app is as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
library(DT)
library(stringr)

    df <- data.frame(empName = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
                    empID = c("J111", "B222", "M333"),
                     empAge = c(23, 41, 32),
                    empSalary = c(21000, 23400, 26800)
                    )


   shinyApp(

      ui = fluidPage(

                    selectizeInput("Search", label = p("Select name"), 
                          choices = as.character(df$empName),
                           multiple = TRUE),
                    hr(),
          fluidRow(
              column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table1")), 
              column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table2"))),
          hr(),
          hr(),
         fluidRow(
                column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table3")),
                     column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table4"))
                 )),



      server = function(input, output, session) {  
           output$table1 = DT::renderDataTable({ df }, options = list(dom = 't'))
              

        df2 <-  reactive ({ 
            (df %>% filter(empName %in% input$Search)%>% select(empID))  
                   })

      output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable({
                   req(input$Search)
               df2()}, options = list(dom = 't'))

      df3 <- reactive({
         if (input$Search != "") {     
               sqldf(paste0("SELECT  *  
                    FROM df WHERE  empName  LIKE '%",input$Search,"%'"))  
           }})                

output$table3 = DT::renderDataTable({ 
            req(input$Search)
              df3()}, options = list(dom = 't'))


         df4 <- reactive ({
               SelectedNames <-stringr::str_c(stringr::str_c("'", input$Search, "'"), collapse = ',') 

      sqldf(paste0("SELECT  empAge, empSalary  
             FROM df  WHERE  empName IN (",SelectedNames,")  "))
                })     

 output$table4 = DT::renderDataTable({ 
              req(input$Search)
             df4()}, options = list(dom = 't')) 
           })
```

I am working with MySQL queries. In Table 1 the data displayed is the whole employee dataframe , I cannot do that for thousands of rows from the original data. The Selectize choices are from a dataframe of UNIQUE values of two columns empName and empID

In table 2 I select the employee names from selectizeInput but display the corresponding IDs .

In Table 3, it only shows one ID value corresponding to selected name value from the selectizeInput.

In table 4, the code allows to query other details from multiple selection of the selectizeInput. In this case I pass the multiple selections and use **stringr** to convert to character strings and pass the variable to the MySQL query.

What I am looking for is to be able to select multiple names from selectizeInput but pass the corresponding multiple employee IDs to the MySQL query to get the results like in Table 4.

Thus basically combine the ability to select names but pass the values of the Id column to allow multiple select in a query.

Any advice or direction towards solving this will be appreciated.

Comment: Your program is already doing what you are expecting.  When multiple names are selected in selectizeInput, IDs corresponding to those multiple selection and other info are shown in tables 2 and 4, respectively.  Only table 3 is displaying one item - last selection.  Perhaps, I am not clear on your expectation.

Comment: @YBS my expectations are to choose empNames in the selectizeInput  but pass the corresponding empID to the queries to get same results in table 4

Answer (score 1):

Choose `empNames` in `selectizeInput` to get `empID` in `df2()` - already done this way in your code. Then use this `empID` on the original dataframe `df` to obtain `df4` as shown below. Then you get the desired `table4`. This is what I understood as your expectation.

```
df4 <- reactive({
      df4 <- df %>% subset(empID %in% df2()$empID) %>% select(empID, empAge, empSalary)
    })
```